# The program can't start because msys-stdc++-6.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: dll, tensorflow, windows-10, bazel, ndk-build

I am trying compiling TensorFlow Library using Bazel. I have download the bazel-0.4.0-windows-x86_64 latest version but when installing the exe it throws me the error. I am using windows 10.

[image: The dll is missing from where I get this dll and how to install]

Comment: Do you have `msys2` installed in the correct location `C:\tools\msys64\`?

Comment: yes I have msys2 installed but on C:\tools location

Comment: If you are interested in having access to Tensorflow (and don't really require Bazel you can just use pip to install it). See [Windows Install Through Pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many days of research on the easiest way to install bazel in windows OS.
I have just used Chocolatey and simply run commands using it, It automatically install all pip files, msys64 and bazel on drive.

The tutorial link

```
https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/windows-chocolatey-maintenance.html
```

Install chocolaty link

```
https://chocolatey.org/
```

Comment: My chocolatey installed version had this problem as well. MSYS2 is installed correctly...